# React components side by side with another component below them

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React and I want to put 2 components side by side, and below in the middle of the screen a button.
I've tried to do something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div style={{float:'top'}}>...</div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <button />
</div>
```

The two components are side by side as I wanted but the button is only under the second (right) component.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve it?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try giving the first div which contains 2 components side by side with display:flex ? That would make two components side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your styling so that the `button` is contained within a similar parent to the two elements above, then you can use the follow styling to center the button below the two elements above:

```css
.container {
    width: fit-content;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.row > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>First element</div>
        <div>Second element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button>button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that in React code you need to rename the `class` attribute to `className`.

**Adding CSS to React**

To include CSS in your React project, you can create a new file called `style.css` in the same directory as your component. So you might have the file structure:

```
MyComponent/
    index.jsx
    style.css
```

Then in your component file (`index.jsx` in this example), import the CSS file with `import "./style.css"` towards the top of the file.

Comment: In a CSS file, you can create a file called `style.css` in the same directory as your component's file and then import it with `import "./style.css"`. Also note that in React code the `class` attributes should be `className`.